# How to get rid of white Spaces in nested list?

Tags: python

I am currently doing a Python course on Code Academy and in this project one part is

> It looks like each data item has inconsistent whitespace around it. First, define an empty list transactions_clean.
> Now, Iterate through daily_transactions_split and for each transaction iterate through the different data points and strip off any whitespace.
> Add each of these cleaned up transactions to the new list transactions_clean.

This is what I have done so far

```
daily_sales = \
"""Edith Mcbride   ;,;$1.21   ;,;   white ;,; 
09/15/17   ,Herbert Tran   ;,;   $7.29;,; 
white&blue;,;   09/15/17 ,Paul Clarke ;,;$12.52 
;,;   white&blue ;,; 09/15/17 ,Lucille Caldwell   
;,;   $5.13   ;,; white   ;,; 09/15/17,
Eduardo George   ;,;$20.39;,; white&yellow 
;,;09/15/17   ,   Danny Mclaughlin;,;$30.82;,;   
purple ;,;09/15/17 ,Stacy Vargas;,; $1.85   ;,; 
purple&yellow ;,;09/15/17,   Shaun Brock;,; 
$17.98;,;purple&yellow ;,; 09/15/17 , 
Erick Harper ;,;$17.41;,; blue ;,; 09/15/17, 
Michelle Howell ;,;$28.59;,; blue;,;   09/15/17   , 
Carroll Boyd;,; $14.51;,;   purple&blue   ;,;   
09/15/17   , Teresa Carter   ;,; $19.64 ;,; 
white;,;09/15/17   ,   Jacob Kennedy ;,; $11.40   
;,; white&red   ;,; 09/15/17, Craig Chambers;,; 
$8.79 ;,; white&blue&red   ;,;09/15/17   , Peggy Bell;,; $8.65 ;,;blue   ;,; 09/15/17,   Kenneth Cunningham ;,;   $10.53;,;   green&blue   ;,; 
09/15/17   ,   Marvin Morgan;,;   $16.49;,; 
green&blue&red   ;,;   09/15/17 ,Marjorie Russell 
;,; $6.55 ;,;   green&blue&red;,;   09/15/17 ,
Israel Cummings;,;   $11.86   ;,;black;,;  
09/15/17,   June Doyle   ;,;   $22.29 ;,;  
black&yellow ;,;09/15/17 , Jaime Buchanan   ;,;   
$8.35;,;   white&black&yellow   ;,;   09/15/17,   
Rhonda Farmer;,;$2.91 ;,;   white&black&yellow   
;,;09/15/17, Darren Mckenzie ;,;$22.94;,;green 
;,;09/15/17,Rufus Malone;,;$4.70   ;,; green&yellow 
;,; 09/15/17   ,Hubert Miles;,;   $3.59   
;,;green&yellow&blue;,;   09/15/17   , Joseph Bridges  ;,;$5.66   ;,; green&yellow&purple&blue 
;,;   09/15/17 , Sergio Murphy   ;,;$17.51   ;,;   
black   ;,;   09/15/17 , Audrey Ferguson ;,; 
$5.54;,;black&blue   ;,;09/15/17 ,Edna Williams ;,; 
$17.13;,; black&blue;,;   09/15/17,   Randy Fleming;,;   $21.13 ;,;black ;,;09/15/17 ,Elisa Hart;,; $0.35   ;,; black&purple;,;   09/15/17   ,
Ernesto Hunt ;,; $13.91   ;,;   black&purple ;,;   
09/15/17,   Shannon Chavez   ;,;$19.26   ;,; 
yellow;,; 09/15/17   , Sammy Cain;,; $5.45;,;   
yellow&red ;,;09/15/17 ,   Steven Reeves ;,;$5.50   
;,;   yellow;,;   09/15/17, Ruben Jones   ;,; 
$14.56 ;,;   yellow&blue;,;09/15/17 , Essie Hansen;,;   $7.33   ;,;   yellow&blue&red
;,; 09/15/17   ,   Rene Hardy   ;,; $20.22   ;,; 
black ;,;   09/15/17 ,   Lucy Snyder   ;,; $8.67   
;,;black&red  ;,; 09/15/17 ,Dallas Obrien ;,;   
$8.31;,;   black&red ;,;   09/15/17,   Stacey Payne 
;,;   $15.70   ;,;   white&black&red ;,;09/15/17   
,   Tanya Cox   ;,;   $6.74   ;,;yellow   ;,; 
09/15/17 , Melody Moran ;,;   $30.84   
;,;yellow&black;,;   09/15/17 , Louise Becker   ;,; 
$12.31 ;,; green&yellow&black;,;   09/15/17 ,
Ryan Webster;,;$2.94 ;,; yellow ;,; 09/15/17 
,Justin Blake ;,; $22.46   ;,;white&yellow ;,;   
09/15/17,   Beverly Baldwin ;,;   $6.60;,;   
white&yellow&black ;,;09/15/17   ,   Dale Brady   
;,;   $6.27 ;,; yellow   ;,;09/15/17 ,Guadalupe Potter ;,;$21.12   ;,; yellow;,; 09/15/17   , 
Desiree Butler ;,;$2.10   ;,;white;,; 09/15/17  
,Sonja Barnett ;,; $14.22 ;,;white&black;,;   
09/15/17, Angelica Garza;,;$11.60;,;white&black   
;,;   09/15/17   ,   Jamie Welch   ;,; $25.27   ;,; 
white&black&red ;,;09/15/17   ,   Rex Hudson   
;,;$8.26;,;   purple;,; 09/15/17 ,   Nadine Gibbs 
;,;   $30.80 ;,;   purple&yellow   ;,; 09/15/17   , 
Hannah Pratt;,;   $22.61   ;,;   purple&yellow   
;,;09/15/17,Gayle Richards;,;$22.19 ;,; 
green&purple&yellow ;,;09/15/17   ,Stanley Holland 
;,; $7.47   ;,; red ;,; 09/15/17 , Anna Dean;,;$5.49 ;,; yellow&red ;,;   09/15/17   ,
Terrance Saunders ;,;   $23.70  ;,;green&yellow&red 
;,; 09/15/17 ,   Brandi Zimmerman ;,; $26.66 ;,; 
red   ;,;09/15/17 ,Guadalupe Freeman ;,; $25.95;,; 
green&red ;,;   09/15/17   ,Irving Patterson 
;,;$19.55 ;,; green&white&red ;,;   09/15/17 ,Karl Ross;,;   $15.68;,;   white ;,;   09/15/17 , Brandy Cortez ;,;$23.57;,;   white&red   ;,;09/15/17, 
Mamie Riley   ;,;$29.32;,; purple;,;09/15/17 ,Mike Thornton   ;,; $26.44 ;,;   purple   ;,; 09/15/17, 
Jamie Vaughn   ;,; $17.24;,;green ;,; 09/15/17   , 
Noah Day ;,;   $8.49   ;,;green   ;,;09/15/17   
,Josephine Keller ;,;$13.10 ;,;green;,;   09/15/17 ,   Tracey Wolfe;,;$20.39 ;,; red   ;,; 09/15/17 ,
Ignacio Parks;,;$14.70   ;,; white&red ;,;09/15/17 
, Beatrice Newman ;,;$22.45   ;,;white&purple&red 
;,;   09/15/17, Andre Norris   ;,;   $28.46   ;,;   
red;,;   09/15/17 ,   Albert Lewis ;,; $23.89;,;   
black&red;,; 09/15/17,   Javier Bailey   ;,;   
$24.49   ;,; black&red ;,; 09/15/17   , Everett Lyons ;,;$1.81;,;   black&red ;,; 09/15/17 ,   
Abraham Maxwell;,; $6.81   ;,;green;,;   09/15/17   
,   Traci Craig ;,;$0.65;,; green&yellow;,; 
09/15/17 , Jeffrey Jenkins   ;,;$26.45;,; 
green&yellow&blue   ;,;   09/15/17,   Merle Wilson 
;,;   $7.69 ;,; purple;,; 09/15/17,Janis Franklin   
;,;$8.74   ;,; purple&black   ;,;09/15/17 ,  
Leonard Guerrero ;,;   $1.86   ;,;yellow  
;,;09/15/17,Lana Sanchez;,;$14.75   ;,; yellow;,;   
09/15/17   ,Donna Ball ;,; $28.10  ;,; 
yellow&blue;,;   09/15/17   , Terrell Barber   ;,; 
$9.91   ;,; green ;,;09/15/17   ,Jody Flores;,; 
$16.34 ;,; green ;,;   09/15/17,   Daryl Herrera 
;,;$27.57;,; white;,;   09/15/17   , Miguel Mcguire;,;$5.25;,; white&blue   ;,;   09/15/17 ,   
Rogelio Gonzalez;,; $9.51;,;   white&black&blue   
;,;   09/15/17   ,   Lora Hammond ;,;$20.56 ;,; 
green;,;   09/15/17,Owen Ward;,; $21.64   ;,;   
green&yellow;,;09/15/17,Malcolm Morales ;,;   
$24.99   ;,;   green&yellow&black;,; 09/15/17 ,   
Eric Mcdaniel ;,;$29.70;,; green ;,; 09/15/17 
,Madeline Estrada;,;   $15.52;,;green;,;   09/15/17 
, Leticia Manning;,;$15.70 ;,; green&purple;,; 
09/15/17 ,   Mario Wallace ;,; $12.36 ;,;green ;,; 
09/15/17,Lewis Glover;,;   $13.66   ;,;   
green&white;,;09/15/17,   Gail Phelps   ;,;$30.52   
;,; green&white&blue   ;,; 09/15/17 , Myrtle Morris 
;,;   $22.66   ;,; green&white&blue;,;09/15/17"""

daily_sales_replaced = daily_sales.replace(";,;",",")

daily_transactions = daily_sales_replaced.split(",")

daily_transaction_split = []

for transaction in daily_transactions:
  daily_transaction_split.append(transaction.split(","))

transactions_clean = []

for outer in daily_transaction_split:
  transactions_clean.append(outer)
  for spaces in transactions_clean:
    transactions_clean.append(spaces.strip())
  

print(transactions_clean)
```

I am stuck on point 8, it states I need to do two for loops, one for the outer, which I think just takes the list and adds it to the `transactions_clean = []` and I must do another for loop that strips the white spaces.

Please see attached screenshot of question:

[image]

Comment: Yes I am aware of strip(). but I am not sure how to impliment it here to get rid of the white spaces

Comment: My Mistake, I was too eager. When you say it does not work what exactly do you mean?
Strings are immutable therefore you can't just iterate over them and call strip. You actually going to have to append it to a new list or else you will have the old values and the new values in the list

Comment: If we have to read the linked task description in order to answer your question (which refers to "point 8", but doesn't appear to contain a textual description of what that is), it needs to be included in the question _as text, not a screenshot_. Screenshots are fine for supplemental information, but a question should be answerable without them. Similarly, sample data should be provided textually -- we can't copy-and-paste from a screenshot to test how our code runs with your data!

Comment: I replaced the screenshot with the error I keep getting. it says ```AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it.

```
for outer in daily_transaction_split:
  for inner in range(len(outer)):
    outer[inner] = outer[inner].strip()
  transactions_clean.append(outer)
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem? If so please accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that in your code there is an infinite loop.
You loop in in a list "transaction_clean" and inside nested loop you keep adding things to the same list . ( That is another reason tuple is better to loop over :) It will break earlier .

I would suggest adding type hints while coding, this way editor may give a warning when type does not fit.

Since it is a learning process I did not want to change your work much
just added a function in the end and a little naming and type hints.

#--------------------------------------------------------------

```
daily_sales_replaced: str = daily_sales.replace(";,;", ",")
daily_transactions_list: list = daily_sales_replaced.split(",")
daily_transaction_process_list: list = []

for transaction in daily_transactions_list:
    daily_transaction_process_list.append(transaction.split(","))
transactions_clean: list = []
for outer in daily_transaction_process_list:
    transactions_clean.append(outer)
transactions_clean_new = []
for spaces in transactions_clean:
    for item in spaces:
        transactions_clean_new.append(item.strip())
print(transactions_clean_new)
```

---

it is a recursive function therefore wee need to make sure
we have at least one final case to exit not to be infinite loop

```
def get_4_item(alist: list):
    if len(alist) < 4:
        print(alist)
        return

    name, amount, color, date_, *others = alist
    print(name, ",", amount, ",", color, ",", date_)
    if alist:
        return get_4_item(others)


get_4_item(transactions_clean_new)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### What is Wrong?

First, let us see what is wrong with your current code. I debugged your code and found that `daily_transactions` is

```py
['Edith Mcbride   ',
 '$1.21   ',
 '   white ',
 ' \n09/15/17   ',
 'Herbert Tran   ',
 '   $7.29',
 ' \nwhite&blue',
 '   09/15/17 ',
 'Paul Clarke ',
 '$12.52 \n'
 ... and much more ...
]
```

Note that

1. It is a list of strings
2. Each element is a string. You should not see any comma any more because of the split earlier.

Next, examine `daily_transaction_split`. The code is:

```py
daily_transaction_split = []

for transaction in daily_transactions:
  daily_transaction_split.append(transaction.split(","))
```

and the the value for `daily_transaction_split` is:

```py
[['Edith Mcbride   '],
 ['$1.21   '],
 ['   white '],
 [' \n09/15/17   '],
 ['Herbert Tran   '],
 ['   $7.29'],
 [' \nwhite&blue'],
 ['   09/15/17 '],
 ['Paul Clarke '],
 ['$12.52 \n']
 ... more ...
]
```

This is a list of lists. What is wrong is you split again. As we noted earlier, the strings in `daily_transactions` do not have any more comma in them, so this split essentially turns each single string into a single-element list. Later on, you call `.split()` on each of these lists and got the error.

#### Observe the Data

I took a couple of minutes to print out the text `daily_sales` and noticed:

- This text spans several lines
- It consists of records, separated by commas
- Within each record, the fields are separated by a `";,;"`
- Each field is surrounded by arbitrary number of white spaces, including new line (`\n`)

#### How Do I Parse This Data?

- We need to split the big text into records by splitting at the commas
- However, since the field-separators are `;,;`, which include the comma, that won't work. We need to replace `;,;` with something else before splitting by the commas. In this case, I choose to use the vertical bar `|`.

Here is my code:

```py
def split_fields(text):
    fields = [field.strip() for field in text.split("|")]
    return fields
    
raw_records = daily_sales.replace(";,;", "|")
records = [split_fields(line) for line in raw_records.split(",")]
```

Notes

`raw_record` is still text, here are the first few lines of it:

```
Edith Mcbride   |$1.21   |   white | 
09/15/17   ,Herbert Tran   |   $7.29| 
white&blue|   09/15/17 ,Paul Clarke |$12.52 
|   white&blue | 09/15/17 ,Lucille Caldwell   
|   $5.13   | white   | 09/15/17,
Eduardo George   |$20.39| white&yellow 
|09/15/17   ,   Danny Mclaughlin|$30.82|   
purple |09/15/17 ,Stacy Vargas| $1.85   |
```

`records` is a list of list. Here are the first few items:

```py
[['Edith Mcbride', '$1.21', 'white', '09/15/17'],
 ['Herbert Tran', '$7.29', 'white&blue', '09/15/17'],
 ['Paul Clarke', '$12.52', 'white&blue', '09/15/17'],
 ['Lucille Caldwell', '$5.13', 'white', '09/15/17'],
 ['Eduardo George', '$20.39', 'white&yellow', '09/15/17'],
 ['Danny Mclaughlin', '$30.82', 'purple', '09/15/17'],
 ['Stacy Vargas', '$1.85', 'purple&yellow', '09/15/17'],
 ['Shaun Brock', '$17.98', 'purple&yellow', '09/15/17'],
 ['Erick Harper', '$17.41', 'blue', '09/15/17'],
 ['Michelle Howell', '$28.59', 'blue', '09/15/17']
 ... more ...
]
```

The function `split_fields()` takes some text such as `'Edith Mcbride   |$1.21   |   white | \n09/15/17   '`, split into fields (by the vertical bars) and strip the spaces.